# share point 365 - workflow only work for me

Tags: email, sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

Good day. I am not getting solution any where so finally i decided to post here.

I am using share point 365 . I created 1 list . once list data updated Email needs to trigger.

I created work flow in share point designer 2013.

In my List i have only 1 Filed.

Field : Manager email id ( Text Box )

in work flow i trigger email for me and manager email id.

But email trigger only for me not my manager.

So check the permission and given contribution permission to "everyone except external users"

Again i tried email not triggered.

Again i given permission for Particular manager .

Then i tried , Email trigger happen.

I have more than 5000 People i cant able to add individual for all 5000 so i used "everyone except external users" but this is not working.

Is this Bug ? or we have work around for that.

Waiting for your response.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You have to create workflow in SharePoint designer.

Follow these steps

- Create a list
- Click on edit . Add a field **Email** having type string.
- save it.
- Open this list in SharePoint designer. Create a workflow.

  [image]
- Click on **action**.
- Under **core action**, click on **send a email** option.
  [image]
- Click on **these users**.
- Then a **define email message** window will be displayed.
- Click on a icon of **To** section.
- Choose **Workflow Lookup for a user** from the list. Click on Add.
- Select Current Item in Date source section and the **Email** field of our list in field section. Press OK.
- Draft a email that you want to send. Press OK.
- Follow same steps for you as user also.
- In transition to stage section,select go to end of workflow.
- Click on workflow setting.
- In Start option, tick all the options.
- Publish it.